# PHP version in HostGator

Tags: php, host

I have one problem with my project, when try to upload a new version in my host (HostGator).

This is the error:

> PHP Startup: SourceGuardian: Unable to initialize module
> Module compiled with module API=20131226
> PHP compiled with module API=20100525
> These options need to match

I change in cPanel the version of PHP 5.4 to 5.6, but when I check the version of PHP in server from connection with putty, I receive the follow message:

> PHP 5.4.45 (cli) (built: Apr 17 2017 15:59:08)
> Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
> Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
>     with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v10.2.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by ionCube Ltd.
>     with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2013, by Zend Technologies

Maybe this can be the problem? I read about this error, but I cant get a solution. I don't know if I doing something wrong.

Comment: Just a note that you should use PHP 7.2 since other versions will become deprecated - [http://php.net/supported-versions.php](http://php.net/supported-versions.php)

Comment: Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cPanel provides 2 different methods of setting the php version. One is called "Select PHP version" which sets the global php version to be used as default for new domains, cron jobs etc, the other is "MultiPHP Manager" which allows you to set different versions of php to be used with different domains under the same cPanel account. You need to make sure "MultiPHP Manager" also lists the correct php version for your domain (It can override "Select PHP version" setting).

Comment: I can solved the problem adding the version of PHP in .htacess in my project folder to the same of the "select PHP version" of the cPanel. Thank you all for the help and advice!

Answer (score 3):

### Simply modifying HTACCESS file:

First of all, Hostgator will deprecate versions older than 7.2 by October 2020.

Second, if the following solution doesn't solve your problem, be sure there's no .htaccess file in a parent folder with different instructions (MySQL module seems to be indicated by the first version indicated in the folder hierarchy, and PHP by the last one).

Use the following code in htaccess file (lines with # at beginning are commented):

```
  # Use PHP 5.4 (will no longer be available in Oct 2020)
#AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
#<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
#    suPHP_ConfigPath /opt/php54/lib
#</IfModule>

  # Use PHP 5.6 (will no longer be available in Oct 2020)
#AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php
#<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
#    suPHP_ConfigPath /opt/php56/lib
#</IfModule>

  # Use PHP 7.1 (will no longer be available in Oct 2020)
#AddHandler application/x-httpd-php71 .php
#<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
#    suPHP_ConfigPath /opt/php71/lib
#</IfModule>

  # Use PHP 7.2
#<IfModule mime_module>
#  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
#</IfModule>

  # Use PHP 7.3
#<IfModule mime_module>
#  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
#</IfModule>

  # Use PHP 7.4 (automatically asigned to new domains since ~Sept 2020)
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
```

Thanks to @anayarojo for the tip for v7.2 (in April 2020).

Comment: I dont know if hostgator support 7.2 because in the Cpanel you can select only 5.4, 7 and 7.1. I have two project in hostgator but only with 7.1 . My  .htacess is something like: AddHandler application/x-httpd-php71 .php. (Same as you posted) If you are using composer in your project i know you can force the update and try to check if this works fine. Sorry for the short help, good luck

Comment: Try with `AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml`

Comment: https://soporte-latam.hostgator.com/hc/es-419/articles/217932208--C%C3%B3mo-cambiar-la-versi%C3%B3n-PHP-#htaccess

Answer (score 1):

The `php` binary invoked from the command line may or may not be the same `php` binary used by Apache. You should use the following PHP script (save it to a publicly accessible web directory and load it in a web browser) to determine which PHP version Apache is configured to run:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

Comment: The version still in 
PHP Version 5.4.45 but i change it in cpanel for 5.6. Maybe need to do it with putty?

Answer (score 1):

Just add this lines to your .htaccess for newer versions of php to work:

For PHP 7.2:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
```

For PHP 7.3:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
```